# how to read spring application console logs from fluentd without writing into file

Tags: fluentd, fluentdata

we are using spring boot java application in our project, there is some log content is missing while writing the log data  into file, so  in place of writing the logs into fluentd we want to ship the logs that directly generating from the console while running application, currently we are using tail plugin in fluentd to ship the logs from file to kibana, is there any way  to collect directly  generated logs in console

```
<source>
@type tail
path /var/log/test.log
pos_file /var/log/td-agent/testlog.pos
tag apache.access
<parse>
@type json
</parse>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can config Fluentd to accept incoming logs from HTTP and by confining your `logback` configuration and adding a new appender for `Fluentd` to send data to it.

see these resource:

- https://medium.com/@federicogaule/collecting-access-logs-into-elasticsearch-1a6f05288f8a
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51202188/2882619
- https://github.com/sndyuk/logback-more-appenders/blob/master/src/test/resources/logback-appenders-fluentd.xml